# error al cargar datos mysql, ajax y php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Tengo un problema al intentar cargar datos anidados en una tabla (local si funciona, pero en el servidor no) este es e query que uso

```
SELECT a.idarticulo,a.idcategoria,c.nombre as categoria,a.codigo, a.nombre,a.stock,a.descripcion,a.imagen,a.condicion FROM articulo a INNER JOIN Categoria c ON a.idcategoria=c.idcategoria
```

y lo imprimo en la tabla de esta manera:

```
    case 'listar':
            $rspta=$articulo->listar();
            $data=Array();

//el while es la linea 54 que muestra el error

            while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {
                $data[]=array(
                "0"=>($reg->condicion)?'<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idarticulo.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="desactivar('.$reg->idarticulo.')"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>':'<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idarticulo.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="activar('.$reg->idarticulo.')"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>',
                "1"=>$reg->nombre,
                "2"=>$reg->categoria,
                "3"=>$reg->codigo,
                "4"=>$reg->stock,
                "5"=>"<img src='../files/articulos/".$reg->imagen."' height='50px' width='50px'>",
                "6"=>$reg->descripcion,
                "7"=>($reg->condicion)?'<span class="label bg-green">Activado</span>':'<span class="label bg-red">Desactivado</span>'
                  );
            }
            $results=array(
                 "sEcho"=>1,//info para datatables
                 "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),//enviamos el total de registros al datatable
                 "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),//enviamos el total de registros a visualizar
                 "aaData"=>$data); 
            echo json_encode($results);
            break;
```

pero me muestra este error desde la consola del navegador en la parte de response:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in /home/uvqm17v7m9yb/fchcontroller.com/ajax/articulo.php:54 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/uvqm17v7m9yb/fchcontroller.com/ajax/articulo.php on line 54

en las pruebas que hice me di cuenta que si elimino del query la parte de categoria, solo dejo artículos, si me lista, pero cuando intento hacerla anidada me da ese error, no sé si será la consulta que está mal o estoy haciendo algo mal con el  fetch_object() en espera de algo que no le estoy dando.

Comment: Revisa tu base de datos en tu servidor el error que recibes es porque hay un error en la sentencia sql y devuelve false. El valor false (booleano) no tiene ningún método/función llamado `fetch_object()` que es el error mostrado.

Answer (score -1):

El problema estaba en un error en la sentencia sql "Categoria" y era "categoria" (la mayúscula)